# How to make my angular app behavior asynchronous

Tags: angular, asynchronous

My application communicate with Spring Boot backend and works fine  
just a little bit question 
when i run my app in two navigators or two pages of same navigator and make change
for example add or delete a candidate then refresh the list

> i want all instances running my application be aware

```
<p-table #dt [value]="listcandidats" [totalRecords]="listcandidats.length" [rows]="5" >
```

Do i miss the **async** pipe for this purpose ?

```
<p-table #dt [value]="listcandidats" [totalRecords]="listcandidats.length" [rows]="5" async>
```

Any explanation is apreciated .

Comment: navigator means two instances of browser/tabs ?

Comment: You need websocket for this. As you want to broadcast that changes has been done on server side, you need two way communication with sever hence websocket.

Comment: Not only websocket, you can share the state through `localstorage`

Comment: Umesh , yes  .
Plochie , Thanks .
Lunin , I think sharing the state in locale storage is not a good professional practice   Did you have an example  link presenting this method